# Favourite tags highlighting lost when selecting different tabs

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, tag-watching, question-lists

If you click between tabs, the questions with your favourite tags are not highlighted:

[image: tab - no highlight]

Performing an entire page refresh (with F5 / refresh button etc) brings back the highlighting:

[image]

Seen on Chrome (46.0.2490.80 m) and IE (11.0.9600.18053) on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix is rolling out with next build (build rev `2015.10.28.3791` on MSE/MSO, `2015.10.28.2910` on sites).